# update tableview textlabel using a button action in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a **button**, a **text field** and a **table view**. What i want is when i enter some text in textfield and click the button(named update) it should update the detailtextlabel of the tableviewcell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,After clicking button add [yourtableview reloadData]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    

if(cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
else
{
    for(UIView *v in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
}


cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;;

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


[[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:10]]; 

cell.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

cell.text = textfield.text; //Yourtextfield text


return cell;
```

}